# Solr server Context Filtering in Auto suggester not working

Tags: solr, autocomplete, filtering

I'm experiencing problem when I try to use Context Filtering with auto suggester. What I want is to filter the suggestions based on ***url field***

Here is my searchComponent:

```
      <lst name="suggester">
        <str name="name">AnalyzingInfixSuggester</str>
        <str name="lookupImpl">AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory</str>
        <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
        <str name="field">main_title</str>
        <str name="weightField">main_title</str>
        <str name="contextField">url</str>
        <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
      </lst>
```

Here are the fields in my schema:

```
  <field name="main_title" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="url" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Example:
I'm searching for "aacsb" and I have two results, which is correct. One is in English and one in German. I want to filter them out and show only the German result.

My urls looks like this:

```
https://www.myWebsite.com/aacsb-dog-lion?german
https://www.myWebsite.com/aacsb-dog-lion?english
```

Here are my queries:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/suggest?&q=aacsb&suggest.dictionary=AnalyzingInfixSuggester&suggest.cfq=-url:english

http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/suggest?&q=aacsb&suggest.dictionary=AnalyzingInfixSuggester&suggest.cfq=-english
```

With these I'm receiving both results. It doesn't matter if we have the field name or not.

When I tried these

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/suggest?&q=aacsb&suggest.dictionary=AnalyzingInfixSuggester&suggest.cfq=url:english
http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/suggest?&q=aacsb&suggest.dictionary=AnalyzingInfixSuggester&suggest.cfq=english
```

I don't receive any results.

I read the documentation several times:[LINK](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_7/suggester.html#context-filtering), but I still can't make it work.

Any help is welcomed.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I pasted the wrong queries, this was the correct:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/suggest?&q=aacsb&suggest.dictionary=AnalyzingInfixSuggester&suggest.cfq=url:\*english\*
http://localhost:8983/solr/myCore/suggest?&q=aacsb&suggest.dictionary=AnalyzingInfixSuggester&suggest.cfq=\*english\*
```

Comment: Just `english` will not match a `string` field with the content `https://www.myWebsite.com/aacsb-dog-lion?english`. You'd be better off by having a separate `language` field that contain only `english` or `german` - i.e. the content you want to filter by.

Comment: When I try to use * asterix sign like that: "\*english\*" it has the same behaviour. I thought about that option too, but my problem is that language is only one of the options I want to context filter.